# replacing specific characters in a line shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sed

I have the following contents in a file

```
{"Hi","Hello","unix":["five","six"]}
```

I would like to replace comma within the square brackets only to semi colon. Rest of the comma's in the line should not be changed.

Output should be

```
{"Hi","Hello","unix":["five";"six"]}
```

I have tried using sed but it is not working. Below is the command I tried. Kindly help.

```
sed 's/:\[*\,*\]/;/'
```

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, please use code tags for sample inputs and expected sample output too as per rules.

Comment: just this line? or all inputs in similar format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your Input_file is same as sample shown then following may help you in same.

```
sed 's/\([^[]*\)\([^,]*\),\(.*\)/\1\2;\3/g'   Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
{"Hi","Hello","unix":["five";"six"]}
```

***EDIT:*** Adding explanation also for same now, it should be only taken for explanation purposes, one should run above code only for getting the output.

```
sed 's/\([^[]*\)\([^,]*\),\(.*\)/\1\2;\3/g'   Input_file
s               ##is for substitution in sed.
\([^[]*\)       ##Creating the first memory hold which will have the contents from starting to before first occurrence of [ and will be obtained by 1 later in code.
\([^,]*\)       ##creating second memory hold which will have everything from [(till where it stopped yesterday) to first occurrence of ,
,               ##Putting , here in the line of Input_file.
\(.*\)          ##creating third memory hold which will have everything after ,(comma) to till end of current line.
/\1\2;\3/g      ##Now mentioning the memory hold by their number \1\2;\3/g so point to be noted here between \2 and \3 have out ;(semi colon) as per OP's request it needed semi colon in place of comma.
```

Answer (score 1):

Awk would also be useful here

```
awk -F'[][]' '{gsub(/,/,";",$2); print $1"["$2"]"$3}' file
```

by using `gsub`, you can replace all occurrences of matched symbol inside a specific field

**Input File**

```
{"Hi","Hello","unix":["five","six"]}
{"Hi","Hello","unix":["five","six","seven","eight"]}
```

**Output**

```
{"Hi","Hello","unix":["five";"six"]}
{"Hi","Hello","unix":["five";"six";"seven";"eight"]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely use RavinderSingh13's answer instead of mine (it's less likely to break or exhibit unexpected behavior given very complex input) but here's a less robust answer that's a little easier to explain than his:

```
sed -r 's/(:\[.*),(.*\])/\1;\2/g' test
```

`()` is a capture group.  You can see there are two in the search.  In the replace, they are refered to as `\1` and `\2`.  This allows you to put chunks of your search back in the replace expression.  `-r` keeps the `(` and `)` from needing to be escaped with a backslash.  `[` and `]` are special and need to be escaped for literal interpretation.  Oh, and you wanted `.*` not `*`.  The `*` is a `glob` and is used in some places in bash and other shells, but not in regexes alone.

edit: and `/g` allows the replacement to happen multiple times.